# Understanding leetcode ZigZag

Tags: data-structures

Can someone explain me the leetcode ZigZag Question?

#### Question [[Link](https://leetcode.com/problems/zigzag-conversion/)]

The string "PAYPALISHIRING" is written in a zigzag pattern on a given number of rows like this: (you may want to display this pattern in a fixed font for better legibility)

```
P   A   H   N
A P L S I I G
Y   I   R
```

And then read line by line: "PAHNAPLSIIGYIR"

Write the code that will take a string and make this conversion given a number of rows:

string convert(string s, int numRows);

#### Example 1:

Input: s = "PAYPALISHIRING", numRows = 3
Output: "PAHNAPLSIIGYIR"

#### Example 2:

Input: s = "PAYPALISHIRING", numRows = 4
Output: "PINALSIGYAHRPI"
Explanation:

```
P     I    N
A   L S  I G
Y A   H R
P     I
```

I am not looking for anyone to solve it. Just help me in understanding the question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming

Comment: @nnnmmm What question can I ask about in stackoverflow says that we can ask question related to **a specific programming problem** or did I get it wrong?

Comment: When numRows = k, the zig-zag consists of k letters going down, then k-1 letters going up and to the right, then k-1 letters going down, then k-1 letters going up and to the right and so forth. To obtain the output, read the symbols left-to-right and top-to-bottom.

Comment: Try similar idea as previous post. see code below. (It's been accepted by Leetcode)

Answer (score 0):

```
  def convert(self, s: str, numRows: int) -> str:
        #
        if numRows <2 or len(s)<numRows: return s
        n = numRows-1
        step = n*2
        res = s[::step]
        for i in range(1,n):
            for v,w in itertools.zip_longest(s[i::step],s[step-i::step],fillvalue=''):
                res += v+w
        return res + s[n::step]
```

Or not using lib. (similar idea)

```
def convert(self, s, numRows):
    step = (numRows == 1) - 1  # 0 or -1  
    rows, idx = [''] * numRows, 0
    for c in s:
        rows[idx] += c
        if idx == 0 or idx == numRows-1: 
            step = -step  #change direction  
        idx += step
    return ''.join(rows)
```